# Inconsistent M-x align-regexp vs. C-u M-x align-regexp behaviour

Tags: emacs, alignment, elisp

I've tried to write some new align rules for emacs and found this strange and inconsistent behaviour. Current buffer contents:

```
"some thing" like => this
   hello => world
and => again
```

After typing <kbd>M-x</kbd>`align-regexp`<kbd>RET</kbd>`[[:lower:]]+\(\s-+\)=>`<kbd>RET</kbd> result looks as desired:

```
"some thing" like => this
             hello => world
             and => again
```

But after <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd>`align-regexp`<kbd>RET</kbd>`[[:lower:]]+\(\s-+\)=>`<kbd>RET</kbd>`1`<kbd>RET</kbd>`1`<kbd>RET</kbd>`y`<kbd>RET</kbd> I get this instead:

```
"some thing" like => this
   hello          => world
and               => again
```

The same (wrong) thing happens if I put this into `align-rules-list`. How to fix this? I want to get the results like first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice question.

When you run *commands* in Emacs, keep in mind that interactive forms are
pre-processing arguments for you.

To see what the *function* finally receives, press <kbd>C-x ESC ESC</kbd>

In this case, you'll see in the former case:

```
(align-regexp 1 57 "\\(\\s-*\\)[[:lower:]]+\\(\\s-+\\)=>" 1 1 nil)
```

and this in the latter

```
(align-regexp 1 57 "[[:lower:]]+\\(\\s-+\\)=>" 1 1 t)
```