# Marker does not point anywhere from align-regexp (Emacs)

Tags: regex, r, emacs, alignment

I am having trouble with the marker in calling an `align-regexp`. Somehow this doesn't work and gives the error "`Marker does not point anywhere`".

The idea of the function is that it searches for a new paragraph, marks it and then performs the align-regexp on it. Why doesn't it work?

```
(defun cleanR-align-smallerthan-dash ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward-regexp "[\n][\n]" nil t) ; confirmed to work
      (mark-paragraph)                            ; the error is probably in here
      (align-regexp (region-beginning) (region-end) "<-"))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regexp you passed is not what `align-regexp` is expecting.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12975000/903943).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're hitting a bug, and that this bug was fixed in Emacs's trunk a while ago.