# Align regexp from emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to use the following elisp function to align text using `=`:

```
(defun align-= ()
  "Align lines by `=`"
  (interactive)
  (align-regexp (region-beginning) (region-end) "="))
```

And I am trying to align the following text:

```
offer = stub('offer')
user = stub('user')
```

But emacs returns the following error:

```
align-region: Marker does not point anywhere
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it working by doing this:

```
(defun align-= (p1 p2)
  "Align lines by =" 
  (interactive "r")
  (align-regexp p1 p2 "\\(\\s-*\\)=" 1 1 nil)
)
```

As far as I understand it `align-regexp` is not receiving what you think it is receiving.

You can test it manually by invoking `M-x align-regexp <RET> = <RET>` and then hitting `C-x ESC ESC` (by default `repeat-complex-command` is bound to `C-x ESC ESC`, you can also use M-n / M-p to move in the history) and you'll see exactly what is passed to `align-regexp`.  I then copied the line into the function.  *(I also used interactive "r" because it's convenient)*

It's working for me on Emacs 24.

Related but not 100% identical to:

[Inconsistent M-x align-regexp vs. C-u M-x align-regexp behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974518)

And also:

[Marker does not point anywhere from align-regexp (Emacs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315064)