# how to make align-current working in lua-mode

Tags: emacs

I am using Emacs with a recent version of `lua-mode` (20200921.1745, commit 345ebfc1e236d9676e7e9f7364493785e7756348) installed with `list-packages`).

The function `align-current` is not working as in `C mode`. How to make it work properly?

Expected:

```
local Var1 = 1
local Var_2 = 2
local Var_33 = 3
> Call M-x align-current
local Var1   = 1
local Var_2  = 2
local Var_33 = 3
```

Result: No change at all

```
local Var1 = 1
local Var_2 = 2
local Var_33 = 3
> Call M-x align-current
local Var1 = 1
local Var_2 = 2
local Var_33 = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I finally wrote a solution based on [Align regexp from emacs lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583702/align-regexp-from-emacs-lisp) and [Inconsistent M-x align-regexp vs. C-u M-x align-regexp behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974518/inconsistent-m-x-align-regexp-vs-c-u-m-x-align-regexp-behaviour) :

It's probably not idiomatic, as I assume that there should be a way to change the behavior of `align-current` in `lua-mode`, to make it work as `c-mode`, but I have no idea how to do that. So this solution is probably just a work-around.

```
(defun lua-align-current ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (mark-paragraph)
    (align-regexp (point) (mark) "\\(\\s-*\\)=" 1 1 nil)))
```

The key-point was this comment:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14587077/10953006